# SwiftUI for macOS - trigger sheet .onDismiss problem

Tags: macos, view, swiftui, modal-dialog

In a multiplatform app I'm showing a sheet to collect a small amount of user input. On iOS, when the sheet is dismissed, the relevant `.onDismiss` method is called but not on macOS.

I've read that having the `.onDismiss` in the `List` can cause problems so I've attached it to the button itself with no improvement. I've also tried passing the `isPresented` binding through and toggling that within the sheet itself to dismiss, but again with no success.

I am employing a `NavigationView` but removing that makes no difference. The following simplified example demonstrates my problem. Any ideas? Should I even be using a sheet for this purpose on macOS?

I just want to make clear that I have no problem closing the sheet. The other questions I found were regarding problems closing the sheet - I can do that fine.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SheetTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}
```

The List view.

```
struct ListView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Patterns").font(.title)
            
            Button(action: {
                isPresented = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Add")
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: {
                doSomethingAfter()
            }) {
                TestSheetView()
            }
            
            List {
                Text("Bingo")
                Text("Bongo")
                Text("Banjo")
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                doSomethingBefore()
            })
        }
    }
    
    func doSomethingBefore() {
        print("Johnny")
    }
    
    func doSomethingAfter() {
        print("Cash")
    }
}
```

This is the sheet view.

```
struct TestSheetView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Enter name", text: $name)
                .padding()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Save") {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 300)
        .navigationTitle("Jedward")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad issue.. you are right. OnDismiss is not called. Here is a workaround with Proxybinding

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Patterns").font(.title)
        
        Button(action: {
            isPresented = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Add")
        })
        
        List {
            Text("Bingo")
            Text("Bongo")
            Text("Banjo")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            doSomethingBefore()
        })
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
            get: {
                isPresented
            }, set: {
                isPresented = $0
                if !$0 {
                    doSomethingAfter()
                }
            })) {
        TestSheetView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm and I've learned a new word today too, (Proxybinding). I appreciate your answer!

Comment: This should have been fixed on macOS 11.5 and later, without the need for a workaround. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_5-release-notes